# How can I use Vue Test Utils to find a component inside a template, inside a slot scope

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to write Unit Test that are able to show that components exist. I am unable to wrangle the test to show that a component exist inside a template, inside a slot scope.

I have gone through github questions, documentation, and google searches. I have tried sync: false, but to no prevail. I have also console logged the wrapper./

The component code

```
<el-table-column label="Status" id='status'>
          <template slot-scope="scope">
            <RequestHttpStatus :data="scope.row.response.httpStatusCode"></RequestHttpStatus>
          </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="User" width="250" id = 'user'>
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <UserNameEmail :data="scope.row.request" :instructor="instructor" :instructors="instructors"></UserNameEmail>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
```

The test

```
    const wrapper = shallowMount(LogsTable, {
      localVue,
      store,
    });
    expect(wrapper.contains(RequestHttpStatus)).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.contains(UserNameEmail)).toBe(true);
  });
```

I want the test to pass.